# What was going on with Will and the lights in Season 2?

Tags: stranger-things

When Will was

> possessed by the Mind Flayer

and questioned about the best way to kill it, the lights flickered on and off in the shed.

Was this supposed to be Will himself having psychic powers? The Mind Flayer having them? The Mind Flayer’s anger causing a power surge generally? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the first season we know that someone from Upside-Down can affect the electricity in the real world - Will made the lights start to glow when he was imprisoned there. In the similar fashion, the Mindflayer (who is still mostly on the other side) was making them flicker when he was near Will.

Comment: The Mind Flayer couldn't have known where Will was, though, or it would have sent the demo-dogs immediately. And it doesn't need to be near someone to control them.